# Apache: can't access css files in virtual host subdirectory

Tags: macos, apache, proxy, virtualhost

I am using apache to setup a virtualhost for my two angular projects, i wanted one of them to be in a subdirectory of the main host, after setup the apache and everything, i changed my **httpdvhost.conf** file and it looks like this right now:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName http://local.example.com
    ProxyPass /chat http://localhost:8100
    ProxyPassReverse /chat http://localhost:8100
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:4200/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:4200/
</VirtualHost>
```

My problem is that my project at port 8100 can't get it's css files as it looks for main.css for example at the path **http://local.example.com/build/main.css** instead of looking for it in the path **http://local.example.com/chat/build/main.css**.

is there any solution for that ? I am a total beginner in this area so i can't find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass your configuration seems to be correct except for a "/".
Change your configuration as following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName http://local.example.com

    ProxyPass /chat/ http://localhost:8100/
    ProxyPassReverse /chat/ http://localhost:8100/

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:4200/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:4200/
</VirtualHost>
```

moreover add some logging to the virtualhost to find out what's happening: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html.

Comment: You are really a savior, thank you, i appreciate your help, i will read about the logs and try to put some logs to see what has gone wrong :)